# Switching to new git branch, revert some changes in NetBeans

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-8

I was editing default layout file in my CakePHP project and created new branch, as I will need it to check new functionality. Problem is, when I switch to new branch, my default layout file reverts to it;s state, like it was few commits before. I need to have it's current version to add new functionality to it, and when merge my branch to master.

Maybe this behavior happened, because my workflow was like this:

- Create new branch
- Commit some changes to master
- Checkout to new branch
- Don't see committed changes

Comment: Did you add and commit your default layour *after* creating your branch? (but *before* switching to that new branch?)

Comment: I commited all my changes to master after creating new branch :) Ant it was before switching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I commited all my changes to master after creating new branch :) And it was before switching

Then it seems normal to see a previous state when you switch to the new branch.
Try merging the branch (say `master`) from which the new branch was created:

```
git checkout newBranch
# see old content
git merge master
# should see newer content
```

Comment: Will I have both master and new branch as two separate branches with same content then?

Comment: @kaktusas2598 at first, just after the merge, yes. But then you will be able to add new commit to `NewBranch`, while maintaining a different history on `master`.